# Angular 14 Service defined in local library and used both in app and library is not singleton

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

### Context

I have an Angular 14 project with 1 application and 1 library. Library is just local, it's not shared anywhere. I have an **ApplicationService** in the library which just acts as a state where I store information about the logged-in user, theme preferences, etc. The **ApplicationService** must be **singleton** and is used **both** in the library and the application. The service itself is exported from the library.

### Problem

The service is **not** singleton. It is constructed twice, in the library and in the application. I have tried a lot of possibilities, including the **forRoot()** in the module, the "**providedIn: 'root'**" attribute, and also using **providers array** inside the module. None did the job and I still have this issue. I have noted that moving the components which uses the service into the web application solves the problem : the service behaves singleton.

### Project

- Library

  - input (module with components which uses the **ApplicationService**)
  - shared (module where the **ApplicationService** is located)
- Web Application

  - dashboard (module where components from "input" module are used)
  - app-module (main app module, must call the **ApplicationService** to initialize data)

### Code samples

app.module.ts

```
const appInitializerFn = (bService: ApplicationService) => {
  return () => {
    return bService.initialize();
  };
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.pwa,
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' },
    { provide: INJECT_ENV, useValue: environment },
    ApplicationService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ApplicationService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIconPacks(fas, far);
  }
}
```

application.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApplicationService {
  constructor(@Inject(INJECT_ENV) private environment: IEnvironment, private themeSelectorService: ThemeSelectorService) {}

  public get baseUrl(): string {
    const idRole = this.idRole;
    return `${this.environment.apiEndpoint}${idRole ? `/${idRole.toString()}` : ''}/api`;
  }

  public get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !!this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  // ommited code ...
}
```

Hopefully someone know a workaround to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: @MikeS. how would the library reference the service of the application? that would imply circular dependency.

Comment: i don't get you. how can the library know what is ApplicationService if it is defined in the application? the application actually references the library, not otherwise. sorry if i misunderstand!

Comment: Try removing ApplicationService from the providers array. the @injecteable({provideIn: root }) will register the service as a singleton available to the entire application.

Comment: @MikeS. the library is dedicated to the application. it will never be used anywhere else. it's just a way for me to separate code in other modules.

Comment: @Jules of course I have tried this. it did not work, the service was still constructed twice.

Comment: @MikeS. ok, perhaps the problem lies in the way you import the library in web application. I don't see it in the imports is that right? Regardless I would remove the service from the provider array since it doesn't do anything and could cause problems.

Comment: @Jules the library is imported through package.json 
`"gephymat-lib": "file:dist/gephymat-lib"`

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation to yours. What we did was create a separate entrypoint for the service.
Create new folder inside your library, let's say `common` within `src`. Inside it add `package.json`

```json
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "public-api.ts"
    }
  }
}
```

and `public-apis.ts`

```
export * from './application.service';
```

Lets assume your library is called `mylibrary`. Now this is the important part: **both library and application need to import this service the same way. Do not use relative imports!** Import it as

```
import { ApplicationService } from 'mylibrary/src/common';`
```

You might need to add some compilerOptions to tsconfig.json to work properly, something like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "mylibrary/src/common": ["src/common/public-api.ts"]
    },
}
```

This way you can also lazy load library if needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but importing the applicationservice in the library with 'mylibrary/src/common' will cause the compilation error 'circular dependency detected'.

Comment: Any other service injected in ApplicationService should be in common as well. It's difficult to help further without knowing exact error and your structure.